# Pytest fixture with scope “class” doesn't works with "setup_class" method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm currently using `pytest_addoption` to run my API tests, so the tests should run against the environment the user uses on the command line. In my test file, I'm trying to instantiate the `UsersSupport` class just once, passing the `env` argument. My code:

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

# Environments
QA1 = 'https://qa1.company.com'
LOCALHOST = 'https://localhost'


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        '--env',
        action='store',
        default='qa1'
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def env(request):
    cmd_option = request.config.getoption('env')
    if cmd_option == 'qa1':
        chosen_env = QA1
    elif cmd_option == 'localhost':
        chosen_env = LOCALHOST
    else:
        raise UnboundLocalError('"--env" command line must use "qa1", "localhost"')
    return chosen_env
```

**users_support.py**

```
import requests


class UsersSupport:

    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.users_endpoint = '/api/v1/users'

    def create_user(self, payload):
        response = requests.post(
            url=f'{self.env}{self.users_endpoint}',
            json=payload,
        )
        return response
```

**post_create_user_test.py**

```
import pytest
from faker import Faker
from projects import UsersSupport
from projects import users_payload


class TestCreateUser:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def setup_class(self, env):
        self.users_support = UsersSupport(env)
        self.fake = Faker()
        self.create_user_payload = users_payload.create_user_payload

    def test_create_user(self):
        created_user_res = self.users_support.create_user(
            payload=self.create_user_payload
        ).json()
        print(created_user_res)
```

**The issue**

When I run `pytest projects/tests/post_create_user_test.py --env qa1` I'm getting `AttributeError: 'TestCreateUser' object has no attribute 'users_support'` error, but if I remove the `scope` from `setup_class` method, this method run on every method and not on all methods.

How can I use the `env` fixture in the `setup_class` and instantiate the `UsersSupport` class to use in all methods?

Comment: Can't you just make `users_support` a class variable?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks for reply. Even so, I get `AttributeError`

Comment: I put a bit more explanation into the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a fixture with class scope, the `self` parameter does not refer to the class instance. You can, however, still access the class itself by using `self.__class__`, so you can make class variables from your instance variables.

Your code could look like this:

```py
import pytest
from faker import Faker
from projects import UsersSupport
from projects import users_payload


class TestCreateUser:
   
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def setup_class(self, env):
        self.__class__.users_support = UsersSupport(env)
        self.__class__.fake = Faker()
        self.__class__.create_user_payload = users_payload.create_user_payload

    def test_create_user(self):
        created_user_res = self.users_support.create_user(
            payload=self.create_user_payload
        ).json()  # now you access the class variable
        print(created_user_res)
```

During the test, a new test instance is created for each test.
If you have a default *function* scoped fixture, it will be called within the same instance of the test, so that the `self` arguments of the fixture and the current test refer to the same instance.

In the case of a *class* scoped fixture, the setup code is run in a separate instance before the test instances are created - this instance has to live until the end of all tests to be able to execute teardown code, so it is different to all test instances. As it is still an instance of the same test class, you can store your variables in the *test class* in this case.

You could also make the class-scoped fixture a *class method*, as you need to access only the class anyway:

```py
class TestCreateUser:
   
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls, env):
        cls.users_support = UsersSupport(env)
        cls.fake = Faker()
        cls.create_user_payload = users_payload.create_user_payload
```

This makes the intent clearer and the code better readable. Note that you have to put the class method decorator after the fixture decorator in this case.